# How to answer a question when another user has provided the answer elsewhere?

Tags: discussion

For example, in [How was the recursive call vulnerability attack conducted via proposal #59 when there were no Yes votes?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/6237/how-was-the-recursive-call-vulnerability-attack-conducted-via-proposal-59-when), a user from DAOhub.org provided the answer.

As I did not provide the answer and wanted to record it down, I marked the answer as a Community Wiki, but this may not be the best way as it allows low reputation users to edit the answer.

What would be the best way to add the user's answer? Just attribute the source?

Comment: Does [this](http://meta.ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/6/87) answer your question?

Comment: Yup. Thanks. I did not want the reputation points for another user's answer, but from your link, I'll just attribute it appropriately.